# Film strip image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Demo]

This is the layout of what I want to do.
2 divs are there.
Below one(rectangle shaped) should be used for image thumbnails which can be scrolled horizontally

Square on above is for the  image that will be shown when clicked on thumbnail

Can anyone guide me how to proceed for thumbnails and scrolling.

Comment: http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55

Comment: They say a picture speaks a thousand words, unfortunately none of them are any use when it comes to HTML. So, what HTML are you working with? What CSS, or JavaScript, have you tried? What went wrong? Do you have a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can play with?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c9Y9X/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building something like this can be quite straight forward but can be time consuming. I think that the best way you should go around this would be to use something that is already been developed and is already out there and is free.

If you take a look there seems to be a lot of people who already have the code built and ready for download similar to what you are asking for

Hope this helps!